# Retrieve a field from response object in angular js depending upon the variable passed

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to use one of the field I am getting in response.data but that field is the one passed in to the function inside my controller. So, I have a func something like this:

```
function driverInfo(interface){
apiserv.get('blahblah').then(function(response){
if (response.data.paramInterfacePassedAbove == null){
        //do when true
}
})
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you mean that the `driverInfo` function will be invoked with the name of a field in `response.data`, and that you need to prepend the fieldname with `default_`, you can change your code to the following:

```
function driverInfo(interface){
  apiserv.get('blahblah').then(function(response){
    if (response.data['default_' + interface] == null){
      //do when true
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: Thank you seth for inputs, I actually tried that but it did not work. Actually, i have not described properly. So e.g, the param passed interface have value 'power' and response.data has field 'default_power' so i have to actually combine the variable with string that I will look into response.data

Comment: I've updated the answer. You just need to add 'default_' to where the field is used. Please accept the answer or upvote if helpful.

Comment: Let me try that. I actually tried to access fields using response.data[''] but it do not return anything. For me it makes sense because response.data is an object correct, so shouldn't it be accessed using dot operator?

Comment: Unless i create a new obj and initialize that object before having response.data into it

Comment: Thanks Seth, but accessing like response.data['default_' + interface] is not working. But it works with response.data.default_power

Comment: `response.data.default_power` is the same as `response.data['default_power']`. If you are saying it doesn't work, then `interface` must not be "power".

Comment: That is strange, if I hard code it like response.data.default_power then it is returning correctly but response.data['default'+interface] it not giving anything

Comment: Wow! It worked as you said, response.data['default'+interface]. The problem was inside the html page I was not using correct controller variable. And also your answer helped as I was not sure how to combine a variable. Thanks

Comment: It has to be 'default_' + interface. Your comment suggests you forgot the underscore. If you actually do have the underscore, the only explanation is that interface does not actually contain the value `power`.

Comment: I have a quick followup question, how can i call a controller function function if my ng-if is true? Right now It is like this <span ng-if="item.result">
              {$ ctrl.hw_interface $}</span>. Instead I am looking something ctrl.driverInfo(item.id) instead of ctrl.hw_interface? Any idea?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145061/discussion-between-seth-flowers-and-user3339691).